# Segmentation fault when attempting to install drive using Go

Tags: software-installation, git, segmentation-fault, google-drive

I am trying to install [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) on my Ubuntu 14.04 from the command line. I have installed Go and Git as the instructions in the link said, but whenever I try to run the command

```
$ go get -u github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive
```

I get the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped). What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a fully updated 14.04 system and it works for me.

A few things would be useful to try:

1. Fully update your system and try again.
2. Use gdb to get a backtrace from the core file.

To get a backtrace the following wiki may help:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

After this the next steps are to collect information and file a bug:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I've managed to move past the segfault error, but now I'm getting a new one --- load cmd/cgo: package cmd/cgo: open /usr/src/cmd/cgo: no such file or directory